# Android In-App Purchase Freedom Hack - How does it work?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Check out this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8sBSQh2kaE

Does anyone know how this hack is implemented?

From what I can see, the app is using the `PackageManager` to query all apps on the device that require `android.vending.BILLING` permission to list out all the apps that support in-app purchases and then goes ahead and does something before launching the app that somehow displays a FAKE credit card when an in-app purchase is attempted on Play.

Since this hack requires the device to be rooted, I'm guessing it's somehow patching the Play client at runtime (?) to do its thing.

This no longer seem to work with most of the apps I've tried - including the one I just implemented using in-app billing v3.0 (consuming the purchase fails, which is a good thing).

I'm still interested in knowing how this used to work (or if it works at all) purely for academic interest.

Comment: I've actually noticed that consuming any test purchase is failing at the moment.

Comment: Nominated for reopening since it is related to a known security flaw in the way the Play billing SDK works. Also related to good Android programming practices such as not exposing your API to other apps to (mis)use.

Comment: For details on one way this could be done, see http://sufficientlysecure.org/index.php/2013/10/29/google-play-billing-hacked/ and the related github code at https://github.com/dschuermann/billing-hack (will convert this comment to an answer if question gets reopened)

Answer (score 4):

In-app Google engine is so primitive... even not worth to spend time. 
The original samples for API 1/2 and API 3 are the basis for many real implementations. But those samples are bad. Really bad. 
Actually a potential hacker needs to hack a couple of functions which easily done in Java.

The good implementation involves a 3rd party (yours) server which verifies actual purchases vs Google In-app server.